# Background MOC's "save:" has no effect (but returns YES)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Consider the following code:

```
[context performBlock:^{
    // add a bunch of objects to context

    NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save MOC because of error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

This is inside a "Store Manager" class, which has getters for 2 MOCs: a standard `.objectContext`and a `.backgroundObjectContext`, which is initialized with the following:

```
backgroundObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
backgroundObjectContext.parentContext = self.objectContext;
```

**My problem**: when I set `context` to `self.objectContext`, everything is fine and the data is saved to the .sqlite file. When I set it to `self.backgroundObjectContext`, no data is written to the sqlite file, but `save:` returns `YES` with no error. I tried logging that context's `registeredObjects` and everything is there. How come the data doesn't get written to the sqlite file?

I've been using the new MOC iOS 5 APIs for a while and this is the first time I'm encountering this issue, so I'm pretty clueless. Is that how you initialize a background MOC in iOS 5? Is there anything else I might be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save a childContext, changes are merged with the parentContext. To be written to a file, you need to save the context at the root.

So in this case:

- you save backgroundObjectContext to merge changes with objectContext
- you save objectContext to save to the PSC

Comment: That was it, thanks! Somehow I always ended up saving the parent MOC later along the way which explains why I never stumbled on this issue before.